# How to insert an entity object when the field of auto generated primary key is left empty in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a winform application for CRUD operation using entity model. It works on multiple table, so which data will be loaded is not known beforehand. Now, I have some tables where primary key is autogenerated by oracle. Now when I try to insert data from datagridview leaving the primary key column empty(datagridview leaves a 0 in that column) it throws exception. How can I solve this problem? Following is my code for loading and inserting data:

```
 StudentEntities context;
 BindingSource stBindingSource = new BindingSource();
 private void btnShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
     dgvLoadTable.Columns.Clear();
     context = new  StudentEntities();
     var rawData = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
     var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData); 
     stBindingSource.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = truncatedData };
     dgvLoadTable.DataSource = stBindingSource;
 } 

 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    context.SaveChanges();
 }

 void stBindingSource_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
 {
    e.NewObject = new TABLEINFO();
    context.AddObject("StudentEntities.TABLEINFO", e.NewObject);
 }
```

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: I can insert multiple column using this code, when the primary key is left empty; it inserts 0 for the first record but doesn't autogenerate the value  and for the next record it gives primary key unique constraint violation, as it has to be unique for each record.